# php mysql table creation advice WHERE certain cell =

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.3

I have a table (parts) that has 2 columns in it, 1000 or so rows. The 1st (parts) column has info stored in each row of it. I am updating the 2nd column via a csv files that I am parsing with PHP. That csv file has 2 columns and about half as many rows. The first column in the updating csv file will need to match the row in the first column of the parts table. Then the 2nd column in the csv file will update the 2nd column in the (parts) table.

Im using this query to loop the info into the parts table:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("csv-file-w-2-columns.csv","r");
require "../db_connect.php";
mysql_select_db("parts", $con);
while(!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);
    $values = explode(",",$line);
    mysql_query("UPDATE parts SET parts_column2='".$values[1]."' WHERE parts_column1='".$values[0]."'");
}
mysql_close($con);
fclose($file);
?>
```

In doing this is takes to long, and my script never finishes. If I do this in small bits at a time it works.

Could anyone help with some advice to speed this up, and any info to why it might be stalling like it has been when I process the whole thing at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your max_execution_time.  You can override this INI setting with [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).  I am guessing that your script is timing out.

As for the structure of your code, there isn't really anything **wrong**, per se.  It's just taking too long according to the server's `max_execution_time` setting.

Comment: ok thanks, so do you recommend just setting running: set_time_limit(0) at the start of my script?

Comment: Sure, if you're using set_time_limit on a case-by-case basis. That said, if you're finding that timeouts happen all over your script and you keep having to use this override, then you're better off revisiting the INI setting rather than making exceptions all over your code.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have to do it via PHP, or if your PHP dbuser has grants for `LOAD DATA INFILE`, you may find it easier to load the csv into a temporary table and then do the `UPDATE` in one go. It will definitely be much faster than running an update query for each line of your file.

e.g.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE receiver(col1 int(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY, col2 varchar(30));
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/myfile.csv' INTO TABLE receiver
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(col1,col2);
UPDATE parts p JOIN receiver r ON (p.col1=r.col1) SET p.col2=r.col2;
```